# Comparing 2 arrays, then push if the condition is met

Tags: javascript, vue.js, loops

I am trying to filter out `emails` that are already existing in `userData`, but my code keeps pushing same data over and over as long as the `email` is not the same.

Here's my code:

```
userData:[ {email: "jane.doe@mail.com", 
           first_name: "Jane", 
           last_name: "Doe"}, 
           {email: "john.doe@sample.com", 
           first_name: "john", 
           last_name: "doe"}, 
           {email: "mary_jane@mail.com", 
           first_name: "Mary", 
           last_name: "Jane"}
],
parseData:[ {email: "jane.doe@mail.com", 
           first_name: "Jane", 
           last_name: "Doe"}, 
           {email: "Johnny_Bravo@sample.com", 
           first_name: "Johnny", 
           last_name: "Bravo"}, 
           {email: "Jayson.Abuela@mail.com", 
           first_name: "Jayson", 
           last_name: "Abuela"}
],
newData: []

var userData = this.userData
var parsedData = this.parseData
function(results) {
            const parsedData = results.data
            for(var j = 0; j < parsedData.length; j++){
              userData.map((data)=>{
                  if(data.email.toLowerCase() != parseData[j].email.toLowerCase()){
                    newData.push(parsedData[j])
                    
                  }else{
                     alert("This "+parsedData[j].email+" already exist.")
                   }
              })
            }
          }
```

I am expecting `user` with `email` of `Johnny_Bravo@sample.com` and `Jayson.Abuela@mail.com` gets push in my newData, it does gets pushed for like 5 times each data. I just want it to be pushed once.

Comment: Seems like an algorithmic design flaw, aka a logical error in thinking that this would work.

Comment: You should add debugging details. [StackOverflow is a question-and-answer site for specific questions about actual code; “I wrote some buggy code that I can’t fix” is not a question, it’s a story, and not even an interesting story.](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Also shouldn't your `complete` callback function have all the data it needs, and not some arbitrary outerscope vars you try to reference?

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited my question. I hope it's much understandable now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just do it the simple way?

```js
const userData = [ {email: "jane.doe@mail.com", 
           first_name: "Jane", 
           last_name: "Doe"}, 
           {email: "john.doe@sample.com", 
           first_name: "john", 
           last_name: "doe"}, 
           {email: "mary_jane@mail.com", 
           first_name: "Mary", 
           last_name: "Jane"}
];

const parseData = [ {email: "jane.doe@mail.com", 
           first_name: "Jane", 
           last_name: "Doe"}, 
           {email: "Johnny_Bravo@sample.com", 
           first_name: "Johnny", 
           last_name: "Bravo"}, 
           {email: "Jayson.Abuela@mail.com", 
           first_name: "Jayson", 
           last_name: "Abuela"}
];

const tempEmails = userData.map(x => x.email.toLowerCase());
const newEmails = parseData.filter(x => !tempEmails.includes(x.email.toLowerCase()));

console.log(newEmails);
```

Couldn't figure out which way around you want it. You can just swap `parseData` and `userData` if this isn't the right way around.

Edit: These are called lambda functions. They're very handy and simple. I'm just using [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create an array of just the email strings. Then I use [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to check each object in the array and if the email key is included in that first map of email strings, exclude it. Simple stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't test that the email isn't in the other array. It's comparing with each element of the other array, and pushing for every one that doesn't match.

Create a `Set` containing all the emails in `parsedData`. Then you can use the `.has()` method to test if the email is already in there.

```
const parsedDataSet = new Set(parsedData.map(({email}) => email.toLowerCase());
userData.forEach(u => {
    if (!parsedDataSet.has(u.email.toLowerCase())) {
        parsedData.push(u);
        parsedDataSet.add(u.email.toLowerCase());
    }
);
```